# Efficiency of Karatsuba algorithm

Tags: java, performance, biginteger

I was trying to build my own version of the RSA cypher.
One of the problem is to have a fast and effient way to multiply two numbers. I didn't understand the `BigInteger` code enought to calculate the time complexity of its method `multiply()` myself, while the reviews said the complexity was O(n²) . I decided to find the code for the Karatsuba algorithm and test it.
The results were... strange.

Pretty much *every* time the common multiplication algorithm works better than Karatsuba, regardless of the number of bits of the two numbers or the variable `limitOfBitsForKaratsubaEfficiency` (i.e. the number of bits the two numbers must have for the *Karatsuba* to be more efficient... in theory).

Now, I studied both the algorithm and the actual implementation: Karatsuba should win both in theory and in practice. Someone knows why the tests favors the common multiplication algorithm?

---

The code I used is below. I tweaked only two lines of code: `limitOfBitsForKaratsubaEfficiency` and `int N = Integer.parseInt("100000");`

```
public static BigInteger karatsuba(BigInteger x, BigInteger y) {

    // cutoff to brute force
    int N = Math.max(x.bitLength(), y.bitLength());
    if (N <= limitOfBitsForKaratsubaEfficiency)     return x.multiply(y);                // optimize this parameter

    // number of bits divided by 2, rounded up
    N = (N / 2) + (N % 2);

    // x = a + 2^N b,   y = c + 2^N d
    BigInteger x1 = x.shiftRight(N);
    BigInteger x0 = x.subtract(x1.shiftLeft(N));
    BigInteger y1 = y.shiftRight(N);
    BigInteger y0 = y.subtract(y1.shiftLeft(N));

    // compute sub-expressions
    BigInteger ac    = karatsuba(x0, y0);
    BigInteger bd    = karatsuba(x1, y1);
    BigInteger abcd  = karatsuba(x0.add(x1), y0.add(y1));

    return ac.add(abcd.subtract(ac).subtract(bd).shiftLeft(N)).add(bd.shiftLeft(2*N));
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start, stopKara, stopNorma;
    Random random = new Random();
    int N = Integer.parseInt("100000");
    BigInteger a,b,c,d;

    for(int i=0 ; i<15 ; i++)
        {
        a = new BigInteger(N, random);
        b = new BigInteger(N, random);
        System.out.printf("The numbers to be multiplied are: \n\t %s \n\t %s\n", a.toString(), b.toString());

        start = System.nanoTime(); 
        c = karatsuba(a, b);
        stopKara = System.nanoTime();
        stopKara = stopKara - start;
        System.out.printf("The karatsuba algorithm has computed %d milliseconds.\n", stopKara);

        start = System.nanoTime(); 
        d = a.multiply(b);
        stopNorma = System.nanoTime();
        stopNorma = stopNorma - start;
        System.out.printf("The common multiplication algorithm has computed %d milliseconds.\n", stopNorma);

        if(c.equals(d)) System.out.println("The two products are equals.");
        else                System.out.println("The two products are NOT equals: the karatsuba method does not works!");
        System.out.printf("The difference Time(Karatsuba)-Time(normalAlgorithm) is: \t %d", stopKara - stopNorma);

        System.out.printf("\n\n\n");
        }
}
    static BigInteger TWO = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
    static BigInteger ONE = BigInteger.ONE;
    static int limitOfBitsForKaratsubaEfficiency = 640;
```

---

EDIT: I found the two methods used by the `BigInteger.multiply()`. I'm definitely no expert in bit-to-bit operations, but the two `for`-cicles let me think that the complexity is O(n²). Karatsuba should be O(n
<sup>1.585</sup>
).

```
  /** Multiply x[0:len-1] by y, and write the len least
   * significant words of the product to dest[0:len-1].
   * Return the most significant word of the product.
   * All values are treated as if they were unsigned
   * (i.e. masked with 0xffffffffL).
   * OK if dest==x (not sure if this is guaranteed for mpn_mul_1).
   * This function is basically the same as gmp's mpn_mul_1.
   */
  public static int mul_1 (int[] dest, int[] x, int len, int y)
  {
    long yword = (long) y & 0xffffffffL;
    long carry = 0;
    for (int j = 0;  j < len; j++)
      {
        carry += ((long) x[j] & 0xffffffffL) * yword;
        dest[j] = (int) carry;
        carry >>>= 32;
      }
    return (int) carry;
  }

  /**
   * Multiply x[0:xlen-1] and y[0:ylen-1], and
   * write the result to dest[0:xlen+ylen-1].
   * The destination has to have space for xlen+ylen words,
   * even if the result might be one limb smaller.
   * This function requires that xlen >= ylen.
   * The destination must be distinct from either input operands.
   * All operands are unsigned.
   * This function is basically the same gmp's mpn_mul. */
  public static void mul (int[] dest,
              int[] x, int xlen,
              int[] y, int ylen)
  {
    dest[xlen] = MPN.mul_1 (dest, x, xlen, y[0]);

    for (int i = 1;  i < ylen; i++)
      {
    long yword = (long) y[i] & 0xffffffffL;
    long carry = 0;
    for (int j = 0;  j < xlen; j++)
      {
        carry += ((long) x[j] & 0xffffffffL) * yword
          + ((long) dest[i+j] & 0xffffffffL);
        dest[i+j] = (int) carry;
        carry >>>= 32;
      }
    dest[i+xlen] = (int) carry;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Your implementation appears to be O(N^2) but less efficient than the built in implementation.

Comment: The simplest answer is probably that the implementors of `BigInteger` know what they're doing.

Comment: @PeterLawrey : Karatsuba is O(n<sup>
1.585
</sup>), while the `BitInteger.multiply` _should_ be O(n²). I edited my original post with the code used by the `BitInteger.multiply`.
@LouisWasserman : _They_ may know, but _I_ still don't understand...

Answer (score 1):

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm

"The standard procedure for multiplication of two n-digit numbers requires a number of elementary operations proportional to n^2\,!, or \Theta(n^2)\,! "

As such you can expect the same big-O, however the implementation will produce much more garbage and is likely to be less efficient without access to the raw underlying data.

Comment: The standard procedure for multiplication of two _n_-digit numbers is **not** the Karatsuba Algorithm: the latter has a complexity of O(n<sup>log 3</sup>). That is why I found so strange that the code is *more* time expensive than the `BigInteger` multiplication method.

Comment: @Argonath Wikipedia suggests it is O(n^2) as does your code, and your results. Where to you get O(n log 3) from?

Comment: @PeterLawrey wikipedia does not suggest that. O(n^1.585) is literally from the article, I don't even know where you're getting that O(n^2) - if it's from the part you quoted, then it's exactly the opposite of what the takeaway from that article should have been. The standard procedure is O(n^2), that is why Karatsuba is better, not why it is the same, because it isn't.